# Where do I put diamond mines on my map?

Tags: geography, geology, natural-resources, mines

I've got a home-brewed D&D setting. Diamonds, in D&D, are needed for resurrection magic, so access to diamonds is literally life and death for any country with clerics capable of casting such spells. The outcomes of wars will likely hinge on which side can control access to diamonds better.

So, where do I put the diamond mines, relative to ecosystem, plate tectonics, etc?

Comment: Beneath layer 16, most commonly between 5 and 12. Make sure your players have an iron or diamond pick or they won't drop.

Comment: Diamonds should be dropped by monsters of about mid-level challenge, so put them relatively far from cities where it id inacessible to noobs. Experienced players will be able to mine diamonds from those monster's drops.

Comment: I like the idea of prospecting for monsters instead of boring old [placer deposits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placer_deposit).

Answer (score 8):

Your setting is magical. Clerics are servants of gods. With that in mind:

**Anywhere you please**

The presence or absence of diamonds in your world isn’t limited by such mundane factors as where volcanoes exist or whether ancient carbon deposits lie buried beneath the surface. You can literally have the Goddess of Diamonds decide to plop a seam of diamonds anywhere. Perhaps a wizard accidentally blew himself up and scattered diamonds across the landscape, or Earth Elementals decided to prank the surface dwellers by putting huge diamond deposits under a loamy flood plain.

Point is: literally anywhere can be a suitable location for your diamond mines as you have so many more justifications available for *why* the diamonds are buried there. Use your imagination, remember why you said they were there, then build that into your world in an inversion of the usual Worldbuilding ‘my things are here because my world says so’ to ‘my things are here, so my world must be this’.

Goddess of diamonds? Drop a buried temple into the mine.
Ancient Accident? The diamonds are cursed and the wizard’s ghost is still around.
Earth Elemental Jokers? They keep playing tricks on the miners.

Or you can go the route of boring old plate tectonics if you really wish...

If you do, the answer is still ‘pretty much anywhere’, as diamonds can form and be transported to the surface anywhere there has *ever* been an upwelling of material from the mantle (specifically a rapid form of eruption that transports the freshly made diamond up before they melt again). These kinds of upwelling can happen damn near anywhere that the crust was once thick enough to support it, but then the diamonds can hang around while the geology around them is modified by... well, geology.

Tiny amounts of diamonds can also be made anywhere a load of carbon rich material got trapped in a subduction zone, or even where meteors have impacted. In those cases the diamonds will be very small, but if your world only cares about the worth of the diamond (who decides if the diamond is worth 10GP??) and uses some form of free-market economy then even small diamonds will rapidly become worth mining.

You get the point. Put the diamonds where it works for your campaign. Justify their presence there later.

Comment: That is not, in fact, true. Diamonds can only form in specific conditions in the upper mantle, 150-200 km down, and it requires old, thick, and generally stable crust to form under, then rapid transport to the surface via a diatreme eruption; if the magma comes to surface as per a normal volcano, the diamonds are dissolved back into the magma and disappear. So no, not in a subglacial volcano, not at a subduction zone (source rock is too shallow).

Comment: @KeithMorrison: Diamond formation in sinking coal beds is rare, but happens, and diamonds have been observed being deposited by glacial activity, or even being washed up on shorelines or produced in meteoric impact craters. I stand by my answer of ‘Anywhere’.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: Feel free to write an answer on the ways our planet produces diamonds in-the-main though. The OP might not want to rely on geological oddities and Gods to explain their super-rich diamond mines.

Comment: Where they've been deposited by glacial outwash it's from the erosion of kimberlitic dykes or pipes in the ground the glaciers have passed over. Diamonds do not form from coal (diamonds that have been dated, aside from asteroid impacts, predate the first life on land, so yeah). You can stand by the assertion, but the assertion is still wrong. See: https://geology.com/articles/diamonds-from-coal/ Note that I was incorrect on one point, namely that it can form in some subduction zones in shallower depths, but still requires a fast eruption to bring to the surface.

Comment: @Keithmorrison: You’ve read from exactly the same articles I have, but seemingly skimmed over different parts to me. Between us we almost form an entire expert!

Comment: @KeithMorrison: Updates abound.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: The kind of diamons which form in specific conditions in the upper mantle are useless for resurrection magic. We are in a world where there exist objects called diamonds which actually work for resurrection magic. Where *those* diamonds are to be found is an artistic decision of the author.

Comment: @JoeBloggs, between the two of us, one of us is a geologist who's worked with diamond producers and explorers in Canada and only referenced that article because I didn't feel like typing the papers on my shelf. There's a reason why diamond exploration isn't going on in, say, Hawaii or Japan.

Comment: @AlexP, I was responding specifically to comments that used the real world situation. When someone uses the real-world situation, one should expect real-world responses.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: My apologies for not having access to your CV and making a reasonable assumption about whether or not you’d done exactly the same thing as me. There’s still time to add your actual expertise on this subject as an answer of it’s own.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: I am intrigued though, is it possible that a volcanic island might play host to diamond bearing formations if the island formed below an already extant diamond-rich area?

Comment: Unless you're talking an island in a lake on a continent, or I suppose an inland sea, no. Oceanic crust is too thin for diamond formation to occur beneath it.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: I didn’t mean diamond formation under the oceanic crust: I meant transport of diamonds to an area under the ocean that is then uplifted by a volcano. As you noted: the earliest diamonds are older than the earliest coal reserves, and coal can be found under oceans, so is it possible for an old cache of diamonds to be ‘picked up’ (and not destroyed) by a volcanic event? If I get a chance tonight I’ll post an actual question on it. Your expertise would be welcomed!

Answer (score 5):

**Almost no-one knows.**

In a D&D scenario, it is underworlders who know where the diamonds are: probably kobolds or [svirfneblin](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_gnome) or some similar creature that is willing to work hard mining for a living.  The svir who mine diamonds know that if the source is found out, powerful interests will move in and take it over, at best enslaving the gnomes to mine more and at worse torturing them until they give up the location of the diamond vaults, then eating them.  So the svirsneblin are extremely circumspect.  They employ a series of middlemen such that none of these (non-svirsneblin!) individuals can betray them.

A good campaign might be an expedition to a fallen svirsneblin mine.  The svir hire your campaigners to oust the monsters which have seized control of the mine, depicting the invaders as a bunch of bumbling umber hulks and owl bears who do not know the value of what they have.  The adventurers will discover that other powerful interests from topside and underneath have realized the same thing, and are all converging on the mine to claim it for themselves.

Comment: This made me laugh. “Diamonds? Oh yeah, they come from the underdark. Where in the underdark? If I told you I’d have to kill you. Seriously. Why are you laughing? Us gnomes are tiny packages of death! Stop laughing!!”